# 'ncu' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

I have **node v16.6.0** and **npm 8.1.3**.

I ran command

```
npm i npm-check-updates -g
```

and then,

```
ncu
```

But it says: **'ncu' is not recognized as an internal or external command**

Answer (score 2):

Instead to `ncu -u`, you can direct use `npx npm-check-updates -u`. It is just short form of `npm-check-updates`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using `nvm` to manage node? If not, it is recommended that you do - it handles adding the correct node bin directory to your path.

If for whatever reason you don't want to use nvm, ensure that the directory returned by `npm bin -g` is in your `PATH`, example:

```sh
export PATH="$(npm bin -g):$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by adding the path of nvc to system's path variable by using this command:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

Comment: didnt work for me